# Honeypot does not filter bots

Tags: javascript, forms, spam-prevention, email-spam, honeypot

I've been getting *blasted* with spam from the forms on my website. So I set up honeypots on both forms, but only one seems to be working. In the spam submissions I'm getting post honeypot, the honeypot fields are all filled out...

It's a static site (stores information in yaml files). The forms use [Formspree](https://github.com/formspree/formspree).

Here's the JavaScript that that handles the forms - the honeypot code is in the submit function:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // get the form elements defined in your form HTML above
  
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("contact-form");
  
  Array.from(forms).forEach(function(form) {
    var status = $(form).find(".contact-form-status")[0];
    
    // Success and Error functions for after the form is submitted
    
    function success() {
      form.reset();
      status.innerHTML = "Thanks!";
    }
    
    function error() {
      status.innerHTML = "Fill out all fields!";
    }
    
    // handle the form submission event
    
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data  = new FormData(form),
          honey = $(form).find('.honey'),
          bot   = false;
      // weed out the bots
      honey.each(function() {
        var input = $(this),
            type  = input.attr('type');
        
        if ('checkbox' === type) {
          if (input.is(':checked')) {
            bot = true;
          }
        }
        if ('text' === type || 'email' === type) {
          if (input.val() !== '') {
            bot = true;
          }
        }
      });
      
      if (bot) { return false; } // exit function upon finding a bot
      ajax(form.method, form.action, data, success, error);
    });
    
  });
  
  // helper function for sending an AJAX request
  
  function ajax(method, url, data, success, error) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        success(xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
      } else {
        error(xhr.status, xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
      }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
  }
});
```

And here's the form in question:

```html
<form id="contact-form"
      class="contact-form"
      action="https://formspree.io/f/xqkgpllv"
      method="POST">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="input" placeholder="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'email'" validate="email">
  <input type="hidden" name="message" value="sign me up for emails">
  <input type="checkbox" name="contact_me_by_fax_only" value="1" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" class="honey">
  <input type="text" name="name_2" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" class="honey input">
  <input type="email" name="email_2" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" class="honey input">
  <textarea type="text" name="message_2" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" class="honey input"></textarea>
  <input type="checkbox" name="contact_me_by_fax_only" value="1" autocomplete="off" class="honey input">
  <button type="submit" class="contact-form-button btn" value="-_-"></button>
  <p class="contact-form-status"></p>
</form>
```

It has a million honeypots because I REALLY wanted this to work.

And the CSS for the honeypot fields:

```css
input.honey {
  position: fixed;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  resize: none;
}
```

I avoided using `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` because I heard bots can pick that out.

If anything jumps out at you as wrong or suspicious, let me know!

Comment: #1 You could use jQuery $.ajax, $(".classname").each ,$(function(){}) thus shortening your code, and make less room for errors, #2 even an error at the end of the submission of the 1st form will stop it from continuing, so you might want to try filling out the forms from the browser console, and check for errors, #3 it could be something wront with the markup of the second form, or if they are using the same id and the bots are using the ID to access the form

Answer (score 0):

You should validate form at `https://formspree.io/f/xqkgpllv` with backend code, not with js preventing event. I could simply disable your JS on my client-side.